# Оттягивание страницы при использовании мака

Tags: css, веб-программирование, mac, safari, background

На маке есть возможность оттянуть страницу и увидеть, что находится выше/ниже/правее границ экрана. Как заблокировать эту возможность либо фон подвинуть? Как повторить это на винде?